# Expo Custom fonts and BottomTabNavigator in app.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to currently load custom fonts using Expo's method found [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/)

As the link suggests, it wants me to add the following code to my app.js file

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    });
  }
```

However, I'm having difficulty adding that code to my existing app.js code, which includes a CreateBottomTabNaviagator, shown below:

```js
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import SavedCollapsibleScreen from "./src/screens/SavedCollapsibleScreen";
import { createBottomTabNavigator,  } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import React, {Component} from "react";
import View from "react-native-web/dist/exports/View";



const Navigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        SavedPlaces: SavedCollapsibleScreen,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'SavedPlaces',
        //headerMode: 'none',
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let IconComponent = Ionicons;
                let iconName;
                if (routeName === 'Home') {
                    iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                    // Sometimes we want to add badges to some icons.
                    // You can check the implementation below.
                    //IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;
                } else if (routeName === 'SavedPlaces') {
                    iconName = `ios-add-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }

                // You can return any component that you like here!
                return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            },
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            showLabel:false,
        },

    },


);



export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

How do I go about adding the custom font code into my already existing app.js?

I've been trying for 3 hours and couldn't get it to work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post expo snack example?

Comment: @Oleg sure; here's basically what I've got so far - I've just used some dummy code. I just want to be able to get custom fonts :( https://snack.expo.io/@yashmorar/help-with-the-fonts!

Comment: @Oleg In the snack above, I would like the text "Local files and assets..." to have a custom font, for example!

Comment: you expo snack link is not  available

Comment: @oleg apologies, please try this snack https://snack.expo.io/@yashmorar/7c0113

Answer (score 0):

Created example:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/test

By using dynamically  createAppContainer method in render of Main App Container when font will be loaded:

```
render()
  {
    const MainApp = !this.state.isLoading? createAppContainer(Navigator):<></>;
     return this.state.isLoading?<AppLoading/>:<MainApp/>;
  }
```